# Uploading large csv to table storage with PowerShell (not sequential)

Tags: powershell, azure-storage

I need an advice how to upload a large csv file (about one minion lines) into a Azure table storage with PowerShell. 
I am aware about `Add-AzTableRow -table $using:table -partitionKey $partitionKey -rowKey $rowKey -property $tableProperty`

https://github.com/paulomarquesc/AzureRmStorageTable/tree/master/docs

Based on tests with a smaller file with 10 000 lines it takes about 10 min to upload, processing sequentially. (It should be about 16-20 hours for 1 000 000 lines)

I have tried the smaller file (10 000 lines) with PowerShell 7 to use `Foreach-Object -Parallel`, but the funny thing is that it takes about 3 times more. From three tests, two uploaded 10 000 lines of file for about 30 mins, one for 47 mins.

Just for comparison, I took less than an hour to upload the one minion lines file with Storage Explorer!
So I was wondering what is the process they are using and could it be used with PowerShell?

I have reviewed the following article:

https://blog.kloud.com.au/2019/02/05/loading-and-querying-data-in-azure-table-storage-using-powershell/

Which should be working, but it returns an error with: `$table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation)`

So my question would be: *Is there any way to load data into Azure table storage in parallel?*

As requested, adding the code used.

**Note**: Code works just fine, but it takes time and I believe It could be faster. Looking for suggestions how to improve.

```
$SaContext = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName).Context
$tableName = 'Table1000000'
New-AzStorageTable –Name $tableName –Context $SaContext
$table = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext).CloudTable
$CSVTable = Import-Csv -Path C:\TEMP\DEMO_CSV\Test-1000000-20200513223059.csv
$i=0
$totalcount = $CSVTable.count

foreach ($entry in $CSVTable) {
    $i++
    Write-Progress -Activity "Importing Data" -Status "Item: $i of $totalcount" -PercentComplete (($i/$totalcount)*100);
    $partitionKey = $entry.ID
    $rowKey = $entry.UserName
    $tableProperty = @{
        'SISID' = $entry.SISID
        'FirstName' = $entry.FirstName
        'LastName' = $entry.LastName
        'Password' = $entry.Password
        'StateID' = $entry.StateID
        'StudentNumber' = $entry.PersonalNumber
        'MiddleName' = $entry.MiddleName
        'Grade' = $entry.Grade
        'Status' = $entry.Status
        'BirthDate' = $entry.BirthDate
        'GradYear' = $entry.GradYear
    }
    Add-AzTableRow -table $table -partitionKey $partitionKey -rowKey $rowKey -property $tableProperty
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you're using for doing entity batch transaction. Also include the exact error you're getting.

Comment: If possible, share some sample data that you're trying to upload.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS There is no error, it works just fine! I am asking for advice how to optimize, as there should be such.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `Which should be working, but it returns an error with: $table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation)`?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS The author of the article present it as a solution, and claims it works, quoting: With my Storage Account being in Central US and myself in Sydney Australia loading the ~26k entries took 4 mins 27 seconds to insert.

When I reproduced the exact same code, it fails on the error specified. I am not trying to troubleshoot this issue, but obviously there are other ways to upload data to table storage, so I am looking for advice from someone who might faced such challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the script you provide, you use the command `Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext).CloudTable` to get a `CouldTable` Object. Its type is `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.CloudTableClient`.
[image]
 So if we want to execute batch operations with the client, we need to set the type of batch operations as `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation`. Besides, please note that all entities in a batch must have the same PartitionKey. If your entities have different PartitionKeys, they need to be in separate batches

For example

```
[Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation] $batchOperation = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation

$e = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity("Hury","test1")
$e.Properties.add("Age","20")
$e1 = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity("Hury","test2")
$e1.Properties.add("Age","25")
$batchOperation.InsertOrReplace($e)
$batchOperation.InsertOrReplace($e1)
$table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync($batchOperation)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much for your suggestion. 
I will test it and will get back to you. Thanks again for taking the time to answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, all credit goes to Jim Xu!! Again, thanks for the support!

I would like to add a couple of comments from my side:

The article quoted, looks like has been changed and the script for uploading is missing.

The issue was, that I was using different object type (as included in the quoted article): `[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableBatchOperation]`

While I had to use: `[Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation]`. 
This is why I was receiving an error, when trying to execute batch: `$table.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation)`.

Adding a working sample script for future references.

**N.B.** The sample provided from Jim Xu works just fine, but there is a limitation of 100 items per batch, so I had to modify it a bit:

```
$SaContext = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName).Context
$table = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $SaContext).cloudtable 
$partitionKey = 'TEST'

[Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation] $batchOperation = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation

$batchCount = 0 # Initialize Batch count

foreach ($rowKey in 1..300){
    $batchCount++
    $entity = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $partitionKey, $rowKey
    # Adding a dummy property Key, Value style
    $entity.Properties.add("Key","Value$rowKey") 
    # Add to batch collection
    $batchOperation.InsertOrReplace($entity) 

    # Maximum number of items per batch is 100
    # Execute batch, when collection = 100 items
    if ($batchCount -eq 100) {
        $table.ExecuteBatchAsync($batchOperation)
        # Initialize bach collection variable object and $batchCount
        [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation] $batchOperation = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation
        $batchCount = 0 
    }
}

# If the last collection ot items is less than 100, execute here
if ($batchOperation.Count -ne 0) {
    $table.ExecuteBatchAsync($batchOperation)
}
```